# Spring @Scheduled with mandatory propagation error

Tags: spring, transactions, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to run a service that is based on the execution by the cron with `@Scheduled` annotation, but every time a database transaction has to be opened within the method annotated with `@Scheduled` I get the an error. Below are my classes:

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.joocebox" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Transacoes -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <task:annotation-driven />
    <beans:bean id="tasksCron" class="br.com.joocebox.quartz.Tasks"></beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

**Class with `@scheduled` annotation**

```
@Service
public class Tasks{

    @Autowired
    private OpenServiceRepository openServiceRepository;

    /*
     * Metodo que fica responsavel por verificar todos os faturamentos no qual
     * a data da venda seja a data atual menos 395 dias com os items sendo de
     * credito e nao gerando debito
     * 
     */
    @Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * ?")
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void demoServiceMethod(){
        long count = openServiceRepository.count();
        System.out.println("O numero de Serviços em aberto é: " + count);
    }
}
```

**Finally my stackTrace:**

```
 15:34:25.005 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
    org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:359) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at br.com.joocebox.quartz.Tasks$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0429f10.demoServiceMethod(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

### EDIT

If I remove the `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)` An IllegalStateException is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at br.com.joocebox.multitenancy.ViatgeTenantResolver.getCurrentTenantFromSubdomain(ViatgeTenantResolver.java:19) ~[ViatgeTenantResolver.class:na]
    at br.com.joocebox.multitenancy.ViatgeTenantResolver.getCurrentTenantId(ViatgeTenantResolver.java:28) ~[ViatgeTenantResolver.class:na]
    at br.com.joocebox.multitenancy.ViatgeTenantResolver.getCurrentTenantId(ViatgeTenantResolver.java:1) ~[ViatgeTenantResolver.class:na]
    at br.com.joocebox.multitenancy.MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository.setCurrentTenant(MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository.java:37) ~[MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository.class:na]
    at br.com.joocebox.multitenancy.MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository.count(MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository.java:48) ~[MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

If I add `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)`:

```
@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * ?")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void demoServiceMethod(){
    long count = jobs.count();
    System.out.println("O numero de Serviços em aberto é: " + count);
}
```

The follow error occurs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at br.com.joocebox.multitenancy.ViatgeTenantResolver.getCurrentTenantFromSubdomain(ViatgeTenantResolver.java:19) ~[ViatgeTenantResolver.class:na]
    at br.com.joocebox.multitenancy.ViatgeTenantResolver.getCurrentTenantId(ViatgeTenantResolver.java:28) ~[ViatgeTenantResolver.class:na]
    at br.com.joocebox.multitenancy.ViatgeTenantResolver.getCurrentTenantId(ViatgeTenantResolver.java:1) ~[ViatgeTenantResolver.class:na]
    at br.com.joocebox.multitenancy.MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository.setCurrentTenant(MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository.java:37) ~[MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository.class:na]
    at br.com.joocebox.multitenancy.MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository.count(MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository.java:48) ~[MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:333) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318) ~[spring-data-commons-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Well, you have marked your method as a one that requires existing transaction but it will not create a new one. So when your method gets called outside of a transaction context, you get an exception. Whats weird about that?

Comment: But I need to mark my method with some method of transaction! If I remove the `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)` An `IllegalStateException` is  thrown (The new error can be viewed in question)

Comment: Why not mark is as: @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) ? So that your scheduled method will always spawn a new transaction? I have a feeling you have no idea how Transactions work in Spring. You should read more on this subject before moving further.

Comment: @R4J, I apologize if I was not clear before, but I've tried this approach and the same error occurs.

Comment: Show us the stacktrace when you marked Propagation as REQUIRED.

Comment: How about showing to us how ViatgeTenantResolver and MultiTenantSimpleJpaRepository looks like? I am especially interesyed in 'ViatgeTenantResolver.getCurrentTenantFromSubdomain' method.